# Parsing a GenBank file

Tags: perl

I trying to parse a GenBank file so I could get the accession number, the definition, the size of the file and the DNA sequence

Is there a way to modify my code and make it shorter and just declare all the variables at once like they do in the book and parse the file in one or two blocks of code?

Comment: I put use strict and warnings. What part is badly indented ? I don't know cause this kind of error didnt show

Comment: Is `@gbfiles` an array of (multiline) records or of (single) lines?

Comment: yes, I tried to split it all in multiline strings

Comment: The for loop you want to insert `"for my $line (@gbfiles)"` seems to indicate that `@gbfiles` now contains single lines?

Comment: I've tidied your Perl code. I've also run it against the data that you show. It doesn't produce the output you say but dies because there is no *molecule type* information in the data that you show. If you make us keep begging you for scraps of information then you are unlikely to get a useful answer. Please read [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and come back with something that we can run to obtain the same results as you. By now that should probably be in a new question

Comment: @HåkonHægland: The statement `my $record = $gbfiles[$i]` implies that `@gbfiles` contains GenBank *records*. (Making `@gbfiles` a *dreadful* identifier!)  And because `@gbfiles` has been created from `split( /\/\/\s*/s, $gbfile )` I doubt if those records are single lines of text. We really need a *lot* more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to [Bio Perl](http://bioperl.org/howtos/Beginners_HOWTO.html#item13), you might find a solution such as the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $in  = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file   => "input.txt",
                           -format => 'GenBank');

while ( my $seq = $in->next_seq ) {
    my $acc = $seq->accession;
    my $length = $seq->length;
    my $definition = $seq->desc;
    my $type = $seq->molecule;
    my $organism = $seq->species->binomial;

    if ($type eq 'mRNA'              &&
        $organism =~ /homo sapiens/i &&
        $acc =~ /[A-Za-z]{2}_[0-9]{6,}/ )
    {
        print "$acc | $definition | $length\n";
        print $seq->seq, "\n";
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

I was able to capture the 5 variables from a sample GenBank file I have (input.txt). It should simplify your code.